# Nuget.config file setup in Jenkins (From Jfrog Artifactory)

Tags: jenkins, nuget, devops, pipeline, artifactory

I'm trying to execute Build action for a dot net core application using Jenkins Pipeline (Cloudbees Jenkins). During the build, when the dotnet restore command is executed, necessary dependency has to be pulled from JFrog antifactory. As of now I have created a local repo, Remote repo and also Virtual repo as suggested by JFrog. What steps have to be taken to make the connection and configuration possible (All the way from Jenkins to Jfrog).

Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the Jenkins Artifacttory Plugin. Refer [this](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Jenkins+Artifactory+Plug-in).